# Change name of factor with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a variable in a data frame that contains integers and some "<31" values.  R recognizes this variable as a factor.

I'd like to set the <31 values to 30, but I've been unable to find an approach to do this.

```
#example my approach so far
a <- factor(c("31","32","43","36","35","46","<31"))
df <- as.data.frame(a)
str(df)
mutate(df, b = as.numeric(if_else(a == "<31", 30, a)))
Error: `false` must be a double vector, not a `factor` object
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the base R `ifelse`, `if_else` is more strict in the return value's class.

Comment: Or `mutate(df, b = as.numeric(if_else(a == "<31", "30", as.character(a))))`. It's slightly faster than your code with `ifelse`.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I try the second option: Error: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector

Comment: And when I try just using ifelse.

Comment: Your code with the changes I've posted works for me. Can you post the exact code you are trying?

Comment: Also, due to factor-to-numeric coercion issues, to change to `ifelse` produces wrong results. The right code is my comment's.

Comment: I had a filter in prior to the mutate line, when I moved that to after mutate it worked.  If you write this up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `if_else` being more strict than base R `ifelse`. From `help("if_else")`:

> Description
>
> Compared to the base ifelse(), this function is more strict. It checks
>   that true and false are the same type. This strictness makes the
>   output type more predictable, and makes it somewhat faster.

And in section Arguments:

> true, false
>   Values to use for `TRUE` and `FALSE` values of condition.
>   They must be either the same length as condition, or length 1. They
>   must also be the same type: `if_else()` checks that they have the same
>   type and same class. All other attributes are taken from true.

So in order to the `mutate` instruction in the question work, coerce both true and false to the same class.
As a side note, I will recreate the data set since there is no need for `as.data.frame`, the correct way is to use `data.frame`.

```
library(dplyr)

a <- factor(c("31","32","43","36","35","46","<31"))
df <- data.frame(a)

mutate(df, b = as.numeric(if_else(a == "<31", "30", as.character(a))))
#    a  b
#1  31 31
#2  32 32
#3  43 43
#4  36 36
#5  35 35
#6  46 46
#7 <31 30
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fct_recode` from `forcats` and then convert it to numeric.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(b = forcats::fct_recode(a, `30` = "<31"), 
         b = as.numeric(as.character(b))) 

#    a  b
#1  31 31
#2  32 32
#3  43 43
#4  36 36
#5  35 35
#6  46 46
#7 <31 30
```